# python logging does not work at all

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to use logging in my small python project. Following the tutorial, I added the code below to my code, but the message wan't logged to the file as it was supposed to.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    filename = "a.log",
    filemode="w",
    level = logging.DEBUG)
logging.error("Log initialization failed.")
```

There was no log file created in the pwd. (I have used the following code to print out the pwd, and I am sure I checked the right directory.) So I manually created the file and ran the code, but the message was still not logged.

```
print "argv: %r"%(sys.argv,)
print "dirname(argv[0]): %s"%os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])))
print "pwd: %s"%os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(os.path.curdir))
```

Has someone any clue what I did wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say `There was log file`, do you mean `there was no log file`?

Comment: Nope, your example works for me. What python version?

Comment: David: Yes, I meant there was no log file generated by the logging mechanism. (I am not sure if this is the supposed behavior though).

Comment: Martijn: I'm running:
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:24:47) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Are you sure the logging code actually happened (did you put it in a function, or something similar)? Did you try putting a print statement next to it?

Comment: Also works for me on Python 2.7. What's wrong with `os.getcwd()` for getting the current working directory? Your method seems a little over-complicated. :)

Comment: David: yes, I actually executed the code step-by-step. that's weird.

Comment: Can you print out the following: 

`print logging.getLogger('').handlers`

Then you'll whether it has correctly added the FileHandler for `a.log` to the root `Logger`.

Comment: Crafty: Oh, I copied that code from another post and didn't change it. It is over-complicated in this case ;-).

Comment: Crafty: I only got this: [<logging.StreamHandler object at 0x0000000002D1BB70>]. does it seem right?

Comment: @Y.P.: That is correct, yes; print `logging.getLogger('').handlers[0].stream` next. I suspect you are looking in the wrong directory.

Comment: @Martijn: now I get <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x00000000020EE1E0>.

Comment: @Y.P.: Then your `basicConfig()` *did not work* because there already *is* a handler present.

Comment: Instead of using `logging.basicConfig`, I changed the code to explicitly create `FileHandler` and add it to the logger. The new code works, but the old one still doesn't.

Comment: @Martijn: Indeed! There was a call to `logging.info("test")` before `basicConfig`. Removing that call solves the problem. I thought it's harmless. Stupid me. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You called `basicConfig()` twice at least; the first time without a filename. Clear the handlers and try again:

```
logging.getLogger('').handlers = []

logging.basicConfig(
    filename = "a.log",
    filemode="w",
    level = logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: where are the other calls?

Comment: @andrew: I called `logging.info` before `basicConfig`, and I thought it was harmless, so I didn't include it in the code above. The [Python logging HowTo][1] has stated this clearly, but I missed it somehow:

**The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(), info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration
facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent
 calls are effectively no-ops.**


  [1]: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html